# sass incremental @loop 0.25,0.50,0.75,1

Tags: html, loops, variables, sass

What I want Is an incremental list form 1 to 100: (+0.25)

```
.width-0_0em  {width: 0em; }
.width-0_25em {width: 0.25em; }
.width-0_50em {width: 0.5em; }
.width-0_75em {width: 0.75em; }
.width-1em    {width: 1em; }
.width-1_25em {width: 1.25em; }
.width-1_50em {width: 1.5em; }
.width-1_75em {width: 1.75em; }
.width-2em    {width: 2em; }
```

This is my code:

```
$max: 1 * 100;
$step: 1 ;

$zero: 0;
$twentyfive: 1 * 25 ;
$fifteen: 1 * 50 ;
$seventyyfive: 1 * 75 ;

@for $i from $step through ceil($max/$step) {
     $value: ($i - 1) * $step + 0;


      .width-#{$value}_#{$zero}em {
        width: #{$value}em;
      }
      .width-#{$value}_#{$twentyfive}em {
        width: $i * 0.25em;
      }
      .width-#{$value}_#{$fifteen}em {
        width: $i * 0.5em;
      }
      .width-#{$value}_#{$seventyyfive}em {
        width: $i * 0.75em;
      }
      .width-#{$value}em {
        width:($i - 1) * $step + 1em;
      }
  }
}
```

Can someone help me with this code please? I don´t know what I'm doing wrong...any exmaple in fiddle or similar will be apreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you want so many class names but you're quite close in your answer. You can use this slightly modified code snippet to get your desired result.

```
@for $i from 0 to 100 {
  $step: 25;
  .width-#{$i}em {
    width: #{$i}em;
  }
  .width-#{$i}_#{$step}em {
    width: #{$i + ($step/100)}em;
  }
  .width-#{$i}_#{$step * 2}em {
    width: #{$i + ($step * 2/100)}em;
  }
  .width-#{$i}_#{$step * 3}em {
    width: #{$i + ($step * 3/100)}em;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes! this is just the solution I want, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm really near from solution, I only need to whrite a"." when I have  ","

```
  $max: 1 * 100;
    $step: 1 ;

    $twentyfive: 1 * 25 ;
    $fifteen: 1 * 50 ;
    $seventyyfive: 1 * 75 ;

    @for $i from $step through ceil($max/$step) {
         $value: ($i - 1) * $step + 0;

          .width-#{$value}em {
            width:($i - 1) * $step + 0em;
          }
          .width-#{$value}_#{$twentyfive}em {
            width: #{$value},#{$twentyfive}em;
          }
          .width-#{$value}_#{$fifteen}em {
            width: #{$value},#{$fifteen}em;
          }
          .width-#{$value}_#{$seventyyfive}em {
            width: #{$value},#{$seventyyfive}em;
          }

  }
```

Comment: Why do you want to give every class a value name?

Comment: Yes, after that I think I will have some "modular" classes like width-3em or width-5em

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nth-child` instead of naming a class every time

**HTML**

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

**SASS**

```
@mixin inc(){
  $step:0.25;
  $max:100;
  @for $i from 1 through ($max/$step){
    $w:$i*$step;
    div:nth-child(#{$i}){
      width:$w+'em';
    }
  }
}
@include inc();
```

Multiply the step with the current Nth child and there you go.
[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Thielicious/htypq32v/)

Comment: It's nice, but It doesn't aswer my question.. (or I didn't understand It)
I wan´t the width increment like: 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.50...to100
The child idea It's nice!

Comment: I have misread your issue before. This should work now, check that Fiddle